# In ruby, how to load raw source code to an instance of Proc?(add `before` `after` hook to class methods)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Normally, we can do this with `Proc` objects:

```
[15] pry(main)> pr = -> { puts "test message" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
=> #<Proc:0x000000057b8a90@(pry):12 (lambda)>
[16] pry(main)> pr.call                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
test message
=> nil
[17] pry(main)> define_method("test_method", pr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
=> :test_method
[18] pry(main)> test_method                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
test message
```

But, what if I have a raw code string and want to load it into a proc? Fake code below:

```
raw_code = "puts 'test message'"
pr = -> { load(raw_code) }   # how to define the `load` method to get this working?
pr.call   # => test message

define_method("test_method", pr}
test_method  # => test message
```

Actually, my original problem is how to write a method hook like this:

```
class TestClass
  def test_method
    puts url
  end
  def test_method_a
    puts url
  end
  before :test_method, :test_method_a do
    url = __method__.split("_").join("/")
  end
end

TestClass.new.test_method # => "test/method"
TestClass.new.test_method_a # => "test/method/a"
```

My problem is more complicated, this is just a simple example to illustrate the key problem.

Comment: Your `TestClass` definition has two problems: First off, to create a module in ruby, you write `module`, not `Module`. The other problem is that for you to be able to use it like that (`TestClass.new.test_method`), and especially given its name, it should probably be a class instead, so that would make it `class TestClass`.

Comment: I'm so sorry, these're writing mistakes. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### My own solution and more detail shown here after reading reply:

Maybe there is a lot of confusion about why does my problem `method hook`  matter with `load raw source code to Proc instance`.

And also, I've solved my problem,now. 
So,let me explain the whole thing in detail:

1, my original problem comes from that I need to extract a bunch of duplicated code at head of some methods of a module just like this:

```
module TestClass
  extend self

  def test_method
    url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")  # duplicated code,need to extract
    puts url
  end

  def test_method_a
    url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")  # duplicated code, need to extract
    puts url
  end
```

2, Then, after a lot of thinking, I come up with an idea, that's get `test_method` `test_method_a`'s source code, and modify the source code by adding `url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")` at the head of it, then redefine the method with new code.

3, After lot of hack, I failed with using `eval` and then, post here  asking help.

4, After reading reply, I make sure `eval` is definitely what I want.

5, Finally, I succeed, code show here:

```
 module TestClass
  extend self

  def test_method
    puts url
  end

  def test_method_a
    puts url
  end

  [ :test_method, :test_method_a ].each do |name|
    method_source_code_ar = instance_method(name).source.split("\n")

    method_source_code_ar.insert(1, 'url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")')

    method_source_code = method_source_code_ar[1..-2].join("\n")

    define_method(name, -> { eval(method_source_code) })
  end

end

TestClass.test_method  # => test/method
TestClass.test_method_a  # => test/method/a
```

6, More concise code version show:

```
module TestClass
  extend self

  def test_method
    puts url
  end

  def test_method_a
    puts url
  end

  [ :test_method, :test_method_a ].each do |name|
    method_source_code_ar = instance_method(name).source.split("\n")

    method_source_code_ar.insert(1, 'url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")')

    method_source_code = method_source_code_ar.join("\n")

    eval(method_source_code)
  end

end
```

7, As `eval`,for me, I think the key to understand it is,thinking not as if you're in writing mode, but as if code was running line by line until reaching the `eval` line code, by that time, what do you want the code to do? Sure, just `eval` the `method_source_code` string.

Answer (score 1):

> how to define the `load` method to get this working?

By spelling it `eval`:

```
raw_code = "puts 'test message'"
pr = -> { eval(raw_code) }   # how to define the `load` method to get this working?
pr.call   # => test message

define_method("test_method", pr)
test_method  # => test message

--output:--
test message
test message
```

> Actually, my original problem is how to write a method hook...

```
class TestClass
  def initialize
    @url = %q{__method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")}
  end

  def test_method
    puts(eval @url)
  end

  def test_method_a
    puts(eval @url)
  end
end

TestClass.new.test_method # => "test/method"
TestClass.new.test_method_a # => "test/method/a"

--output:--
test/method
test/method/a
```

> Actually, my original problem is how to write a method hook like this:
>
> ```
> Module TestClass
>   def test_method
>     puts url
>   end
> ```

The problem is that `url` can never refer to a value outside the def.  A def cuts off the visibility of local variables outside the def.

```
class TestClass

  def test_method
    puts @url
  end

  def test_method_a
    puts @url
  end

  def self.before(*method_names, &block)
    method_names.each do |method_name|
      alias_method "first_#{method_name}", method_name
      define_method(method_name, block) #This changes __method__ inside the block from nil to method_name

      alias_method "second_#{method_name}", method_name
      define_method(method_name) do
        send "second_#{method_name}"  #This method executes: @url = __method__.to_s.split(...
        send "first_#{method_name}"   #This method executes: puts @url
      end
    end
  end

  before :test_method, :test_method_a do
    @url = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")
  end
end

TestClass.new.test_method # => "test/method"
TestClass.new.test_method_a # => "test/method/a"

--output:--
test/method
test/method/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version: `load` loads code from a **file**. If you want to run code that you already have in a string, you can use `eval`, or one of it's friends, `class_eval` or `instance_eval`.

If you do end up using `eval`, however, you need to be *very* careful so that you won't accidentally run code that could delete your files, install malware or whatever.

Longer version: For a working version (in ruby 2.2.3) with `load`, you would need to put your `TestClass` class in a file:

```
class TestClass
  def test_method
    puts "OHAI"
  end
end
```

Let's save this class in a file called "test_class.rb".

With that, the following should just work:

```
pr = -> { load(File.join(__dir__, "test_class.rb")) }
pr.call
TestClass.new.test_method
```

This will not solve your "original problem", but it should give you a little better understanding on how `load` works.