# Why doesn't UnboundMethod have the instance method `source` since it has `source location`? And how can I hack this?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Why doesn't `UnboundMethod` have the instance method `source` since it has `source location`? And how can I hack this? Does ruby's metaprogramming not good enough to do this?(Does ruby's metaprogramming suck?) If so, can you recommend a better language for me to get this done?

This is an example to explain my question:

```
# test.rb

class TestClass
  def test_m_a
    puts "test_m_a path: #{path}"
  end
  def test_m_b
    puts "test_m_b path: #{path}"
  end

  instance_methods(false).each do |name|
    puts "source_location: #{instance_method(name).source_location}"
    method_source_code_ar = instance_method(name).source.split("\n")
    method_source_code_ar.insert(1, 'path = __method__.to_s.split("_").join("/")')
    method_source_code_ar.insert(-2, 'puts "#{__method__}  end"')

    method_source_code = method_source_code_ar.join("\n")
    eval(method_source_code)
  end
end
```

run in pry:

```
➜  ~  
➜  ~  pry
[1] pry(main)> require './test.rb' 
source_location: ["/home/yanying/test.rb", 5]
source_location: ["/home/yanying/test.rb", 8]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
=> true
[2] pry(main)> TestClass.new.test_m_a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
test_m_a path: test/m/a
test_m_a end
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> TestClass.new.test_m_b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
test_m_b path: test/m/b
test_m_b end
=> nil
[4] pry(main)>
```

run in irb:

```
  ~  irb
2.1.5 :001 > require './test.rb'
source_location: ["/home/yanying/test.rb", 5]
NoMethodError: undefined method `source' for #<UnboundMethod: TestClass#test_m_a>
    from /home/yanying/test.rb:13:in `block in <class:TestClass>'
    from /home/yanying/test.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/yanying/test.rb:12:in `<class:TestClass>'
    from /home/yanying/test.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/yanying/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/yanying/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/yanying/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :002 >
```

This is the original proglem referenced to:

[In ruby, how to load raw source code to an instance of Proc?(add `before` `after` hook to class methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538522/in-ruby-how-to-load-raw-source-code-to-an-instance-of-procadd-before-after/33603492#33603492)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source location is remembered for debugging purposes, so that stack traces can be generated with helpful information.

Source is not remembered (as it would waste a lot of memory); only the compiled code is. You can see *that* with `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm(instance_method(name))`.

The `source` that works for you in Pry is implemented by Pry (well, actually by `method_source` gem that Pry depends on): it reads the file at `source_location`, then finds the expression at the `source_location` line.

EDIT: how can you hack this?

```
$ gem install method_source
$ irb -r method_source
> puts Method.instance_method(:source).source
# => def source
#      MethodSource.source_helper(source_location, defined?(name) ? name : inspect)
#    end
```

> Does ruby's metaprogramming suck?

No, it's actually among the best around. But you normally don't need to get the source. If you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, there is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: My actual problem is basically same as the example. I need to add `before` `after` hook to class methods and don't want to involve in 'instance variable' . Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538522/in-ruby-how-to-load-raw-source-code-to-an-instance-of-procadd-before-after/33603492

Comment: And thanks, add gem `method_source` solved my problem.